# Set does not return unique elements from list of alphanumeric tuples - why? (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, set, combinations

I am extracting data on cells from a pd.DataFrame above a certain value. I'm storing the index, column header and value in a tuple. These tuples then get appended to a list. The layout of the dataframe I'm taking the values from means I extract each element twice and I need to store each combination only once. From reading previous peoples efforts set(list) should give these unique elements but on a mock dataset which should produce the single result ('Pathway1','Pathway2', 0.6) it reports two permutations.

Does anyone know why set is not working in this case? I know the lists need to be identical and to my eye they are (even down to the type of each tuple component (string, string, float)). Out of desparation I tried coercing the float to a string with no improvement.

For completeness most of the code is given (simplied a bit). The block at the bottom is where the problem arises. Code follows:

---

```
#Import modules
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Define trial sets

s1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
s2 = ["A", "B", "C"]
s3 = ["A", "B", "F"]
s4 = ["A", "B", "G", "H", "I"]
s5 = ["X", "Y", "Z"]

slist = [s1,s2,s3,s4,s5]

#Create an empty list to append results to
result1 = [] 

#Calculate Jaccard index between every entry
    #This is computationally inefficient as most computations are performed twice to generate a full results matrix to make mapping easy. Making half a matrix is more complicated but would be possible within the loop. Empty values would still have to be coded for though so in terms of storage of the final results matrix I don't think there should be much difference

for i in range(len(slist)):
    for j in range(len(slist)):
        result1.append(len(set(slist[i]).intersection(slist[j]))/len(set(slist[i]).union(slist[j])))

#Define result matrix dimensions
shape = (len(slist), len(slist))

#Convert list to array for numpy
rarray = np.array(result1)  

pathway_names = ["Pathway1", "Pathway2", "Pathway3", "Pathway4", "Pathway5"]

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data = rmatrix, index = pathway_names, columns = pathway_names)

#List all pathways with Jaccard index > x unless PathwayName = PathwayName

x = 0.5
temp =[] #A temporary list for holding lists of tuples which will contain permutations
```

The issue lies in:

```
for k in range(len(slist)):
    index = dataframe.index[dataframe.iloc[k]>x]
    for l in range(len(index)):
        if index[l] != dataframe.columns[k]:
            temp.append((index[l], dataframe.columns[k], dataframe.iloc[l,k]))
print(set(temp))
```

The output I get from printing `temp` is

```
{('Pathway1', 'Pathway2', 0.6), ('Pathway2', 'Pathway1', 0.6)}
```

But I require (in any order):

```
('Pathway1', 'Pathway2', 0.6)
```

Thanks for any help you can provide,

Angus

Comment: `pathway_review` is a list to which you append sets. How does it become a set of tuples all of a sudden?

Comment: I'll remove pathway_review it doesn't help make the problem clear and given the trial dataset it has no purpose. When I talk about the output here I mean print(set(temp))

Comment: It's not clear whether you've noticed that `('Pathway1', 'Pathway2', 0.6)` and `('Pathway2', 'Pathway1', 0.6)` are completely different tuples; one has `'Pathway1'` in front and the other has it second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that tuples are ordered, therefore `('Pathway1', 'Pathway2', 0.6)` does not equal `('Pathway2', 'Pathway1', 0.6)`.

To fix the issue, initialize `temp` as a `set` and sort any tuple before adding to it.

```
temp = set()
for ...:
    ...
    the_tuple = ...
    temp.add(tuple(sorted(the_tuple)))
print(temp)
```

Comment: Thanks, a variation on this has worked:

    temp = []

for k in range(len(slist)):
    index = dataframe.index[dataframe.iloc[k]>x]
    for l in range(len(index)):
        if index[l] != dataframe.columns[k]:
            unsorted_list = [index[l], dataframe.columns[k], str(dataframe.iloc[l,k])]
            sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list)
            temp.append(tuple(sorted_list))
print(set(temp))

As people have pointed out the key was that tuples are ordered